# How to Determine If .NET EXE was started by another process

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, vba

Forgive me if my title is not accurate, I did my best to describe my issue.

Here's the details, I can modify accordingly:

I've been upgrading a VB6 application to a .NET (VB.NET and C#) application to be used in Excel. Using my application's ProgID, I can query it in Excel VBA using:

```
CreateObject("MyExe.MyApp")
```

Since I believe my app is a single-instance application, when I call `CreateObject` and it is already running, it just returns me that running instance. All is fine there.

My issue is, when it is NOT running, it will launch a new one right? That's my problem in my .NET application. You see, in VB6, when you use `CreateObject`, it will change my `App.StartMode` to `VbSModeAutomation = 1`

My VB6 application handles this accordingly. However, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent way of doing this for a .NET application. In fact, it says right on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984469%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) MSDN page:

> StartMode - No equivalent. In Visual Basic 6.0, this property was used
>   to start an application as an ActiveX component. ActiveX component
>   creation is not supported in Visual Studio .NET.

So ultimately, my question is: how do I determine when my .NET application is started from this call to `CreateObject` versus starting it manually (or via standealone, like a shortcut or etc.)?

Comment: could you pass a commandline arg to indicate the start method?

Comment: Have you checked the command line arguments? I know that IE, for example, is launched with `-Embedding` when started this way. I'm not sure if this is standard or configurable.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Plutonix I'd have to research if that's possible with `CreateObject` I'm not sure yet.

Comment: @DarkFalcon For the VB6 Application, yes - it sends `-Embedding` as an arg. But the .NET app doesn't have any commandline args unfortunately it seems.

Comment: Of course it has them. Your `Main` function needs to take a `string[]` and that is the arguments. You probably have your `Main` function defined without any arguments. Both are allowable, but obviously one way makes it a bit difficult to get the arguments...

Comment: NET **does** have commandline args - several methods in fact: `Environment.CommandLine`, `Sub Main` and `Environment.CommandLineArgs()`.  I think there is anohter in the VB namespace also

Comment: Sorry, miscommunicated there. I meant it isn't *sending* any args to the .NET app, compared to how the VB6 app already was sending `-Embedding`

Comment: if the CreateObject method cant/wont send args, then modify the shortcut to pass an arg.  The absence of an arg would then indicate it was started by CO

Comment: @Plutonix - I used `Environment.CommandLine` to get information from the command line. Found out I was getting the command line wrong. When started from Excel, it seems to be sending an additional `-Embedding`! So I can use this to determine when it starts from Excel. If you write up an answer, since you got me to the right path, I'll mark it up :)

Answer (score 4):

.NET does not as easily let you create an out-of-process COM server, like VB6 does with that VbSModeAutomation property.  The supported scenario is COM+ hosting, your [ComVisible] class needs to derive from the ServicedComponent class.

There's a dedicated [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306296) that summarizes the required steps pretty well.  The in-depth MSDN articles [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x7357ez%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, learned that yesterday from you too :) Thanks for the help. Again though, I found a way to "skip" around this. When started from Excel using `CreateObject` I have an additional `-Embedding` command line arg, which I can handle accordingly. So far, when starting stand-alone, this `-Embedding` arg doesn't exist. Yuck?

Comment: That's an option that is highly specific to OLE.  OLE embedding is dead as a doornail, not even legacy Microsoft programs like Office support it anymore.  Pretty important to focus on finding practical solutions, there's nothing you've posted so far that strongly suggest that you truly need an out-of-process server.

Answer (score 1):

Checking for a parent process is quite tricky but you can find the information in the [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class - ParentProcessID property. If this is not set then your application was not started by another application.

Comment: Uhm... if it's not started by another process how did it come to be? (sounds kind'a philosophical, but unless you are System[4] you'll have to have/had a parent... if ppid is null it means you are an orphan not that you didn't have a parent)

Comment: @MrPaulch I suppose I could check `IFF` the parent process is Excel, then handle it the same was as if `App.StartMode = 1`

Comment: You could do *that*. Though it's not what the answer was suggesting. I made a complete answer on how to check for the PPID [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603971/how-to-suppress-default-browser-from-opening-while-vb-net-webbrowser-encounter-s/22622444#22622444)

Comment: @MrPaulch I said that it was not started by another application not that it didn't have a parent. Semantically I wouldn't call a system process an Application, nor does windows (task manager). Your code is good though.

Comment: I guess we had a different definition of the word *Application*. Or rather I had used an incorrect one in my thougths.

Comment: It just occured to me. Even though it's nice to be disagreeing on semantics... `Win32_Process` only tells you who your parent (**process**) is or if your parent is dead... so please corret the sentence in your answer: `If this is not set then your application was not started by another application`

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the CommandLine to determine how it starts.  It does not appear that `CreateObject` allows you to pass command args, but as you noted, `-Embedding` seems to automatically get sent.  Alternatively, maybe you could modify the shortcut method to pass some fake argument and its absence could indicate a `CreateObject` start method.

NET supports several ways to get the commandline:

[Environment.CommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Environment.CommandLineArgs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I think there is another in the VB Namespace but it returns a collection of objects rather than String or String array of parsed args (space delimited).

You can also modify your Sub Main:

```
 Public Sub Main(args() As String)
```

NET will fill in the array with the parsed commandline